# Delete all from table before XML data is written to table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I'm writing the nodes of an XML to the database columns but I want to delete all (*) from the database before XML is written to the table again.

Right now if a user with userid '100' is inserted into the db, the code doesn't check for dupes and I'll have more than 1 userid '100's in the db. I need to check if the column id (for example) matches the id node of the xml. if there is a match, update the v and a nodes, if no match in the table then insert the id, v, and a nodes into the table

I created a function, `private void deleteFromDb(string table)` but I cant seem to call it (if I did it correctly in the first place) before the XML data is inserted into the table. But this wipes out all the data but the last person who accesses the page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Net"%>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Data"%>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient"%>
<%@ Import namespace="System.IO"%>
<%@ Import namespace="System.Xml"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server" language="C#">

public class XML
{
    internal string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ToString();

    private void add2Db(string table, string sqlRows, string sqlValues)
    {
        string sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})", table, sqlRows, sqlValues);
        using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConn))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    private void deleteFromDb(string table)
    {
        string sql = String.Format("DELETE *", table);
        using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConn))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    public void parseXML(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        string tsLogpro = "";
            string sqlRows = "";
            string sqlValues = "";

            //SELECT NODE: logPro
            foreach (XmlNode logPro in doc.SelectNodes("broadcasting"))
            {
                tsLogpro = logPro.SelectSingleNode("@ts").InnerText;

                //SELECT CHILD NODE: logPro
                foreach (XmlNode child in logPro.ChildNodes)
                {

                    //GET ROWS
                    foreach (XmlNode rows in child.Attributes)
                    {
                        sqlRows += rows.Name + ", ";
                    }

                    //GET VALUES
                    foreach (XmlNode values in child.Attributes)
                    {
                        sqlValues += "'" + values.InnerText + "', ";
                    }

                    sqlRows = sqlRows.Substring(0, sqlRows.Length - 2);
                    sqlValues = sqlValues.Substring(0, sqlValues.Length - 2);

                    //Response.Write("\n\n");
                    //Response.Write(sqlRows);
                    //Response.Write("\n" + sqlValues);

                    add2Db("flashcoms_chat7_broadcast", sqlRows, sqlValues);

                    sqlValues = "";
                    sqlRows = "";

                }
            }
        }
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-type", "text/plain");

    HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    System.IO.Stream body = request.InputStream;
    System.Text.Encoding encoding = request.ContentEncoding;
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(body, encoding);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();

    if (Request.Params["action"] != string.Empty && Request.Params["action"] == "test")
        {
            doc.InnerXml = "" +
               "<broadcasting ts=\"12345\">" +
                    "<u id=\"1\" v=\"true\" a=\"true\" />" +
                    "<u id=\"2\" v=\"true\" a=\"true\" />" +
                    "<u id=\"3\" v=\"true\" a=\"false\" />" +
                    "<u id=\"4\" v=\"true\" a=\"true\" />" +
                    "<u id=\"5\" v=\"true\" a=\"true\" />" +
                "</broadcasting>";
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        doc.InnerXml = s;
     }

    // Starting at line 111 in your original post
    XML oXML = new XML();
    oXML.deleteFromDb("f_chat7_broadcast")
    oXML.parseXML(doc);
    Response.Write("Done");
    Response.End();
}
    /*
     * 
     * 
   SET ANSI_NULLS ON
   GO
   USE [DB]
   GO
   SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
   GO
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[f_chat7_broadcast](
       [id] [nchar](100) NULL,
       [v] [nchar](10) NULL,
       [a] [nchar](10) NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
   GO
     * 
     */
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>blah blah</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="Form2" method="post" runat="server"><% Page_Load(null, null); %></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you calling Page_Load(null, null)?  Page_Load will fire automatically (it's part of the life cycle of the page).

Comment: Is the table meant to persist data over a period of time, or is more a temp table?  If the former, deleting the data in the table prior to loading the data from the XML document just to avoid duplicate user ids strikes me as being lazy.

Comment: well Tim, do you have a solution to check the 'id' node against the 'id' column? if the id exists in the table only update the a and v columns and if not, insert the id, a, and v data from the XML into the table?

Comment: Use T-SQL to simply check if a row already EXISTS with the id; IF there is, update the values, ELSE insert a new row.  Try that, and if you can't get it to work, post what you tried and ask for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

this

```
string sql = String.Format("DELETE *", table);
```

should be

```
string sql = String.Format("DELETE FROM {0}", table);
```

another point:
as far as I can see you don't have setup any exception handling (try / catch...) which is a bad practice...

Comment: sorry, i put the completely wrong use. I need to update the v and a columns if the id already exists. Sorry